# Media query orientation issue from soft keyboard and problem with iPad orientation

Tags: css, media-queries

I've set my media queries to be:

```
@media screen and (min-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (orientation: landscape) {
  // code here
}

@media screen and (max-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (orientation: portrait) {
     // code here
    }
```

I've had to include the `device-aspect-ratio` to offset the change in orientation caused by the soft keyboard in Chrome mobile. It works well enough, but when testing on iPad, I've found that when turning it to landscape mode, it sticks to showing the portrait styles instead of landscape.

It works for iPad on landscape when I remove the `min-device-aspect-ratio` for the landscape styles, but then this causes the orientation to change from portrait to landscape on Chrome mobile view with soft keyboard. Does anyone know of any media queries to account for both these situations?

Comment: This might help https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ipad-specific-css/

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you switch it around? ie

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
   // code here
}
```

Comment: Nothing changes, still have the same problem